# Accessing the correct Range when "on edit" triggered function modifies a Google Sheet's structure

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, eventtrigger

I need to move one row to another sheet if a specific value was entered, e.g. to archive data.

I've written the following code, which works perfectly so long as the user does not trigger it a second time before the first has finished. The first one will move the corresponding row, but the second "edit" event will move the different row, as the rows numbers were changed by the previous `onEdit()` call. For example:

Customer edits row[1] and row[3] and marks them for archiving.

The first `onEdit` will remove `row[1]`, so the `row[3]` will become `row[2]`, but in the second `onEdit` call, `range.getRow()` still returns **3**, so `row[3]` will be removed and not `row[2]` as expected.

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  moveArchived(event);
}

function moveArchived(event)
{
  var sheetNameToWatch = "Queue";
  var columnNumberToWatch = 15; // column A = 1, B = 2, O = 15, etc.
  var valueToWatch = "ARCHIVE";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Archive";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = event.source.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch)
  {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var response = ui.alert('Do you want to move this row to Archive sheet?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if (response == ui.Button.NO)
      return;

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }  
}
```

How can I modify my code to prevent this, i.e. to ensure I move the actual range?

Answer (score 0):

I thought that using the [lockService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service) would be the ideal solution for this use case since its purpose is to prevent concurrency between two or more function executions but I'm a bit disappointed by the result I get...

Maybe someone will find a better way to implement it or suggest another solution ;-)

In the mean time, you can give a try to this code below.  I made a few changes, one of them is the ability to handle multiple cells at once (if a user paste many cells with 'ARCHIVE' in it).

I changed also the range definition using the range coming from the event itself and, finally, I used an installable onEdit instead of the simple one because I had the feeling that it worked more reliably (although there is no objective reason for that... maybe I dreamed ;-))
and changed the onEdit function name to avoid double trigger.

So you'll have to add a new onEdit trigger from the ressources menu in the script editor.

After all these warnings the only thing I can say is that it works ... but not always ! and that's IMHO the most annoying situation when using scripts ... so -as I already said - try before buy and cross fingers hoping someone will improve it shortly.

code below :

```
function moveArchived(event){
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  // Wait for up to 30 seconds for other processes to finish.
  lock.waitLock(30000);
  var sheetNameToWatch = "Queue";
  var columnNumberToWatch = 15; // column A = 1, B = 2, O = 15, etc.
  var valueToWatch = "ARCHIVE";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Archive";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = event.range;

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue().indexOf(valueToWatch)>-1)
  {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var response = ui.alert('Do you want to move this/these row(s) to Archive sheet?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if (response == ui.Button.NO)
    {
      lock.releaseLock();
      return
    }
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    range.moveTo(targetRange);
    for(var n = event.range.rowStart ; n < event.range.rowEnd ; n++){
      sheet.deleteRow(n);
    }
  }  
  lock.releaseLock();
}

function installOnEdit(event){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(event));
  moveArchived(event);
}
```